# How to perform mathematical operations with values of Unit type?

Tags: c#, asp.net, types

I have three variables (width of different controls in asp.net). Their type is `Unit`.

I want to do the following action. Example:

```
Contol1.Width = Control2.Width - Control3.Width
```

Now I get an error:

> Can't apply operator "-" to operands of type "System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit".

How I can perform mathematical operations with this values?

Comment: Have you tried `Contol1.Width.Value`

Comment: Edited: Sorry, I don't sight my mistake. I want to assign result to Control1.Width

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit` is a structure that has a [`Value`-property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.unit.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that you can use.

```
Contol1.Width.Value - Control2.Width.Value - Control3.Width.Value
```

Comment: Thanks, It helps me. I can accept this only through the 5 minutes. :(

Answer (score 2):

It has been already said that you could use [Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.unit.value%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property of the Unit class but you should not forget that some controls may have different [measures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.unit.value%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

What if one control's size is measured in pixels, while other's is in points?

```
public Unit Subtract(this Unit unit, Unit toSubtract)
{
    if (unit.Type != toSubtract.Type)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Types are not compatible");

    return new Unit(unit.Value - toSubtract.Value, 
       unit.Type);
}

...

control1.Width = control2.Width.Subtract(control3.Width);
```

It is not as clear and simple but more safe if your controls' measures are incompatible. If you have time you could add some conversion logic in place of the exception throwing.